# How to set an Ansible role's variables file relative to the host?

Tags: variables, roles, ansible

Here is the detail of my playbook:

**Playbook tree**

```
├─ devops
|  ├─ roles
|  |  ├─ mongodb
|  |  ├─ haproxy
|  |  ├─ monit
|  |  |  ├─ vars
|  |  |  |  └─ main.yml
|  |  |  └─ ...
|  |  └─ ...
|  ├─ hosts
|  ├─ play1.yml
|  └─ play2.yml
```

**hosts**

```
[play1]
...instructions...

[play2]
...instructions...
```

**play1.yml**

```
---
- hosts: play1
  user: root
  roles:
    - haproxy
    - monit
```

**play2.yml**

```
---
- hosts: play2
  user: root
  roles:
    - mongodb
    - monit
```

### **Question**

I would like to use a different variables file for monit depending on the host (play1.yml or play2.yml). How I can do the trick?

Many thanks

Comment: That is AFAIK not possible. A role is completely independent of your inventory. If you want host specific variables you have to create vars in `host_vars` or `group_vars`. Those folders can either be relative to your playbook or relative to your inventory file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Malo,

You should use  "host_vars" and not hosts_vars

```
 /host_vars/play1/mongodb.yml
```

Also,  `play1`  should match the name of the host that you have configured in your hosts inventory.

Answer (score 4):

According to http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout the recommended layout is as follows:

```
production                # inventory file for production servers
stage                     # inventory file for stage environment

group_vars/
   group1                 # here we assign variables to particular groups
   group2                 # ""
host_vars/
   hostname1              # if systems need specific variables, put them here
   hostname2              # ""

library/                  # if any custom modules, put them here (optional)
filter_plugins/           # if any custom filter plugins, put them here (optional)

site.yml                  # master playbook
webservers.yml            # playbook for webserver tier
dbservers.yml             # playbook for dbserver tier

roles/
    common/               # this hierarchy represents a "role"
        tasks/            #
            main.yml      #  <-- tasks file can include smaller files if warranted
        handlers/         #
            main.yml      #  <-- handlers file
        templates/        #  <-- files for use with the template resource
            ntp.conf.j2   #  <------- templates end in .j2
        files/            #
            bar.txt       #  <-- files for use with the copy resource
            foo.sh        #  <-- script files for use with the script resource
        vars/             #
            main.yml      #  <-- variables associated with this role
        defaults/         #
            main.yml      #  <-- default lower priority variables for this role
        meta/             #
            main.yml      #  <-- role dependencies

    webtier/              # same kind of structure as "common" was above, done for the webtier role
    monitoring/           # ""
    fooapp/               # ""
```

Notice the `host_vars/` directory. There you can have include host-specific variables that your role can use later on.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible allows you to separate your data from code. Now this data is what you define in the form of variables.

When it comes to variables, there are precedence rules which come in to play when you have the same variable defined at multiple places.  The recommendation is

- Provide default variables in  roles -> defaults/  directory. Thats what it is for. Sane defaults.
- Override those defaults from other places, such as host_vars. thats where you would put host specific vars. And thats the answer to your question.
- However, if you specify the same var in roles -> vars directory, that would take higher precedence. so be careful about this one.

Apart from these, there are few more precedence rules. However, creators of ansible recommend defining variable only at one place.  I personally would not follow that rule, and would use sane defaults and hosts/group specific vars.